# Setting the pixel format of an existing Bitmap in GDI+

Tags: c++, gdi+, gdi

How do I set the PixelFormat property in a GDI+ Bitmap if I can't use one of the constructors that allow me to specify it?  It looks like the PixelFormat property itself is read-only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using the following method of creating a second bitmap with the desired pixel format and drawing the original image on to it.

```
Bitmap *pTempBitmap = new Gdiplus::Bitmap(_Module.m_hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(lImageResource));
m_pGDIBitmap = new Bitmap(pTempBitmap->GetWidth(), pTempBitmap->GetHeight(), PixelFormat32bppARGB);
Graphics TempGraphics(pTempBitmap);
TempGraphics.DrawImage(m_pGDIBitmap, Point(0,0));
```